# What does container option in waitFor in React Testing Library do? Why doesn't it limit the scope of find?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

- From the doc

  > The default `container` is the global `document`. Make sure the elements you wait for are descendants of `container`.
  >
  > https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async/#waitfor

  (There is no more online resource I can find anything about this `container`...)
- What I tried:

  ```
  /**
  * @jest-environment jsdom
  */

  import { setImmediate } from 'timers'; // https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/8558
  global.setImmediate = setImmediate;

  import { jest } from '@jest/globals';

  import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
  import { RenderResult, act, findByText, prettyDOM, render, screen, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react';

  // import { PrintUtil } from '../../src/util/print/PrintUtil';
  // const { printHtmlHltAnsi } = PrintUtil;

  describe('RandomTest', () => {
    test('simpleTest__1', async () => {
      const renderResult = render(
        <div>
          <div id="div1">
            <code>search one</code>
            <code>search two</code>
            <code>search three</code>
          </div>
          <div id="div2">
            <code>find one</code>
            <code>find two</code>
            <code>find three</code>
          </div>
        </div>
      );

      const elt_div2 = renderResult.container.querySelector<HTMLElement>(`#div2`) ?? (() => { throw new TypeError(); })(); // prettier-ignore
      // console.log(printHtmlHltAnsi(elt_div2));

      await waitFor(
        () => {
          renderResult.getByText(/one/);
        },
        {
          container: elt_div2,
        }
      );
    });
  ```
- And I got error:

  ```
  > tlightchat-main@0.0.0 randomUtest H:\Using\TLightChat\tlightchat-main
  > node --experimental-vm-modules ./node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --runTestsByPath ./test/randomTest/Utest1.test.tsx

  (node:19232) ExperimentalWarning: VM Modules is an experimental feature and might change at any time
  (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
  FAIL  test/randomTest/Utest1.test.tsx
    RandomTest
      × simpleTest__1 (1039 ms)
      ○ skipped simpleTest__2

    ● RandomTest › simpleTest__1

      Found multiple elements with the text: /one/

      Here are the matching elements:

      <code>search one</code>


      <code>find one</code>


      (If this is intentional, then use the `*AllBy*` variant of the query (like `queryAllByText`, `getAllByText`, or `findAllByText`)).

      <body>
        <div>
          <div>
            <div id="div1"><code>search one</code><code>search two</code><code>search three</code></div>
            <div id="div2"><code>find one</code><code>find two</code><code>find three</code></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </body>

        34 |     // console.log(printHtmlHltAnsi(elt_div2));
        35 |
      > 36 |     await waitFor(
           |           ^
        37 |       () => {
        38 |         renderResult.getByText(/one/);
        39 |       },

        at waitForWrapper (node_modules/.pnpm/@testing-library+dom@9.3.3/node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/wait-for.js:162:27)
        at Object.<anonymous> (test/randomTest/Utest1.test.tsx:36:11)

  Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
  Tests:       1 failed, 1 skipped, 2 total
  Snapshots:   0 total
  Time:        5.412 s
  Ran all test suites within paths "./test/randomTest/Utest1.test.tsx".
   ELIFECYCLE  Command failed with exit code 1.
  ```
- It seems like `waitFor`:

  - is finding the element in the **whole** `document` -- which makes it find duplicates -- error case,
  - **not** finding the element **inside** `elt_div2` -- which it should find only 1 element inside -- correct case.

  So, **Why is that?**
- (However if I use `findByText` things are fine, the scope is indeed limited this case:)

  ```
      await findByText(elt_div2, /one/);
  ```

Comment: If you want to scope the query why not use https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-within/

Comment: @jonrsharpe seems like another way to do things. But I still wonder why the `container` option doesnt work?